# Select Date query in SQL

Tags: sql-server, date, select

i have a date column now i want to write "S" when there is sunday  like if i have data like this

```
datecolumn 

1-1-2017
2-1-2017    
3-1-2017    
4-1-2017    
5-1-2017    
6-1-2017    
7-1-2017    
8-1-2017    
9-1-2017    
10-1-2017    
11-1-2017    
12-1-2017    
13-1-2017
```

in this if on date there is Sunday day then how to write "Sun" instead on date like this

```
select datecolumn from table1


datecolumn 

1-1-2017    
2-1-2017    
3-1-2017    
Sun    
5-1-2017   
6-1-2017    
7-1-2017    
8-1-2017    
9-1-2017    
10-1-2017    
Sun    
12-1-2017   
13-1-017
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW, datecolumn) = 1 THEN 'Sun' ELSE CAST(datecolumn AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) END AS datecolumn
FROM table1
```

Hope it helps.

PS - might have to modify the `CAST(datecolumn AS NVARCHAR(MAX))` to a `CONVERT` if you need the dates in a specific date format.

Comment: will you please this DATEPART(DW, servicestartdate) = 1 what DW and why you write 1?

Comment: What that does is check which day of the week (DW) that date is in, and Sunday is always 1

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2012+, using IIF Statement.

```
select
IIF(DATEPART(DW, DateVal) = 1, 'Sun', Convert(varchar(12), datecolumn, 103)) AS datecolumn
from tableName
```

Comment: will you explain this please what is DW and why you write =1?

Comment: DATEPART is one of the date time function which returns integer. DW is weekday here, like for date of Sunday (2017-07-23), DW value is 1, Monday 2, Tuesday 3...so on.